# Jaeger how to trace a specific message based on ID

Tags: java, microservices, jaeger

I've been playing with Jaeger and I have a scenario where I don't know how to make it work.

Usually all the examples I have seen so far are like this:

ServiceA

- Start span
- Call ServiceB
- End span

So that way you can get the response time including serviceB's time.

Now I have this scenario:

ServiceA -> Queue (SQS) -> ServiceB -> SNS topic -> ServiceC

ServiceA won't wait for ServiceB response as ServiceB will delivery the message to ServiceC via SNS. The only that I have for each message is an ID

Is it possible to trace message with the ID.

For example I want to know how long a specific message based on ID takes from serviceA to serviceC.

Any idea? thanks

Comment: Did you figure out anything by this time?